# converting char* to char** using a delimeter string

Tags: c

Hey I'm trying to convert a char* array to a char** 2d array. This is the function I've been working on, but I keep getting seg faults. It seems like strsep is causing this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix this.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char** oneD_to_twoD(char* str){
  int cur_size = 20;
  char* free_me = str;
  char ** output = malloc(sizeof(char*)*sizeof(str));
  int i = 0;
  char *toks = "\n\t \r\v\f";
  char* add_me = str;
  str = strsep(&str, toks);
  printf("%s\n", "here");
  while(str != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", "here");
    strcpy(output[i], add_me);
    add_me = str;
    i++;
    if(i == cur_size){
      cur_size *= 2;
      output = realloc(output, sizeof(char*)*cur_size);
    }
    str = strsep(&str, toks);
  }
  return output;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){

  char *str = malloc(sizeof("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23"));
  str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23";
  char** str2 = oneD_to_twoD(str);
  for (int i = 0; i < 23; ++i)
  {
    printf("%s\n", str2[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str = "1 2..."` Sorry to say, that's completely wrong. It does not place that string into the allocated memory. It makes `str` point to a string *constant*. You cannot pass `str` to `strsep` as that function will attempt to modify the string. Use `strcpy` to copy a string into a buffer.

Comment: `char**` 2d array is an oxymoron. A pointer is not an array. You don't have a 2D array and nothing which can point to one.

Answer (score -1):

Memory allocation for `output` which is a double pointer, is wrong. That's why you are getting segmentation fault

```
char **output=malloc(sizeof(str));
for(i=0;i<sizeof(str);i++)
{
    output[i]=malloc(sizeof(char*));
}
```

This is the proper way to initialize a char**.You need to apply these changes in your realloc also .If there is still problem kindly let me know. Thanks

Comment: a swing and a miss

Comment: what seems to be the miss

Comment: The contents of a char** is already char* elements for one thing.